# how can i go back to the visual studio after clicking add-in from tools

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, add-in

I am making  add-in (plug in )for visual studio 2010 .
We know that add-in will be visible inside tools menu, whenever we click tools menu in visual studio 2010.

Whenever i click the add-in  it loads one windows forms and some quering all will do on windows forms .

But i am not able to go back to visual studio to see other things whenever add-in running.

I just  want control to go back to visual studio IDE , eventhough add-in form  is runnning aside .

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but usually when you're working with Visual Studio extensibility, you want to use two separate instances of Visual Studio. You probably want to run one of them in the "Visual Studio Experimental Hive" (search for that).

Comment: yeah ofcourse when i run the project , it will open the another visual studio instance, in that another instance when i  click add-in from tools windows form will load,(in case of my add-in ), after the form is loaded, some kind of work is done , in between that if i want to go to visual studio ide(other instance only), the control will not allowing me to go , unless i complete the execution of add-in or close the add-in

Comment: Are you stopped at a debugger breakpoint in one window?

Comment: No i didnt add any debug point

Comment: see my add-in is working completely as i written the code in that , the thing is i need to close the add-in or complete excecution and close to go back to visualstudio (same instance where add-in is running),. suppose in between i want to go to IDE its not allowing me

Answer (score 0):

Use Form.Show() instead of Form.ShowDialog() to create a non-blocking window.

Even better, use [dte.Windows.CreateToolWindow2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.windows2.createtoolwindow2%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) to create a VS tool window to host your content.